# What does "have a global reach" mean here?

Tags: sentence-meaning

I ran into this:

> Tourism is more than just about reaching a destination – **tourism has a global reach**. Every time we travel, we become part of a global movement that has the power to drive positive change for our planet and all people. <[Source](http://wtd.unwto.org/content/official-messages-world-tourism-day)>

What does that mean? does it mean it has a global purpose?

Comment: I'm closevoting as General Reference. **Reach,** noun: sense 23: *the extent or distance of reaching*, sense 24: *range of effective action, power, or capacity.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is like "global *influence*". Check this definition of [***reach***](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/american/reach):

> 18) the distance or extent covered in stretching, obtaining, influencing, etc.